# How to Implement Calendar in CrossPlatForm(Xamarin )

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to implement android and ios default calendar in Xamarin.form.

i would like to access default iphone and android calenders.

please share any examples or tutorials its very help full to me

Comment: https://github.com/TheAlmightyBob/Calendars/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the calendar control by writing a custom renderer as given [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Calendar-Control)

Or enroll for a [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) of Syncfusion and use their Calendar Control.